# Show a text as texture with OpenGL ES 2.0

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I'm developing an Android 2.2 application. I use C++ to manage all OpenGL ES 2.0 stuff.

I want to show a text with OpenGL, but I don't know how (I'm very, very new with it).

I read that I can render common strings to textures, and simply draw those textures. But how can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has already been answered [right here on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android).

A very basic and useful approach is to store a rendered alphabet in a texture. Then you can write your own method to lookup every character of a passed string and draw it to the screen.

Comment: That solution isn't C++ :-(  I think he's after a C++ answer.  (So am I BTW)  There are some ES 1.1 solutions out there, but not an obvious 2.0 solution yet.  FTGLES is close.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Cairo](http://cairographics.org/OpenGL/) to render text (with any unicode font) to a texture and then map the texture directly.