# How to add a text to OpenGL ES 10 in Android (for beginners)?

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android)

I know that if you wanna draw 3D object you need buffors for colors, indices, coords and Override some functions, but I do not know what to do to see text (string) on my emulator with OpenGL ES.
 I try to look in google but I didn't see any tutorials or samples that I could understand.

I saw this: 
[Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android) 
but I don't understand it.

What should I do to draw "Hello world"?

Comment: Duplicate question.  There's no text in OpenGL ES - you have to do it yourself.  Google again - the help is out there.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL does not support text drawing. There are some extensions/libraries that do this, but AFAIK none is for Android.

Easiest solution would be to create bitmaps, one for each letter and then display them so that they make "words".