# Can i Make Text in 3D in android

Tags: android, opengl-es, textview

I am trying to make a TagCloud and trying to put text on a cube. But I am not able to specify the Z index in text. Is it possible ?

I was reading about it found this discussion [Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android)

Any Ideas ?

Comment: I found one of the way is to change those text into bitmap and place those bitmaps in the space. But this could be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Draw glyphs/strings to a texture(s).
2. Render [view-aligned](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/billboarding/) quads with your text at whatever Z you want.