# Drawing text in open gl isn't clear

Tags: android, opengl-es

[image]

I'm using this font.png but in game it doesn't look clear.How can i draw a clear text in my game?Rendering text to a texture like in [Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android) is more logical then my solution?

Comment: Post image or describe your problem better please. Do you mean it's not transparent? Or that its blurry?

Comment: @Tim i mean it's blurry.It's not clear.

Comment: You'll get more help with an in-game image of the problem, and your code that you use to draw it. As is there's no way to answer this question.

Comment: what format are you using to create the texture? it should be GL_RGBA

Comment: @Nick I'm working with opengl 1.1.How can i set it to GL_RGBA?

Comment: Depends if you are using a 3rd party graphics system, or if you're using raw opengl apis. In the case of raw opengl, you would pass in a value of GL_RGBA as the format AND internal format arguments of glTexImage2D(). If you are using a 3rd party library, you'll have to check their documentatation about how to enable the alpha channel in textures.

Comment: @Nick I pass as an internal format of glTexImage2D but i can't understand where i will pass GL_RGBA in values.In vertices?And where?

Comment: glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels); - the first GL_RGBA specifies the format this texture will be stored as inside the video card, second GL_RGBA argument specifies the format of the pixel data you are uploading. In your case, since you are using a 32bit png with alpha, and you want alpha when you render, you would use GL_RGBA for both.

Comment: @Nick I'm sorry but in my GLUtils i have only this : GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL10.GL_RGBA, bitmap, 0);.I can't find this method.What is the wrong ?

Comment: sorry, I am used to using the C++ API. The one GL_RGBA is all you should need with that function, so long as your source texture(the png file) has an alpha channel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you enabled blending for your OpenGL context?

try this code in OnSurfaceCreated():

```
gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);
```

**edit:**
this code works with your texture:
just rename your texture to "text.png" and put it in res/raw/

```
//////////////////////////////
// TextureTestActivity.java

package com.TextureTest.TextureTest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Context;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;

public class TextureTestActivity extends Activity {
    private GLSurfaceView mGLView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mGLView = new TextureTestSurfaceView(this);
        setContentView(mGLView);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mGLView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mGLView.onResume();
    }
}

class TextureTestSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    public TextureTestSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        setEGLConfigChooser(false);
        setRenderer(new TextureTestRenderer(context));
    }
}

//////////////////////////////
// TextureTestRenderer.java
package com.TextureTest.TextureTest;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.ByteOrder;
import java.nio.FloatBuffer;
import javax.microedition.khronos.egl.EGLConfig;
import javax.microedition.khronos.opengles.GL10;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.opengl.GLES10;
import android.opengl.GLSurfaceView;
import android.opengl.GLU;
import android.opengl.GLUtils;
public class TextureTestRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Context context;
    int textureID;

    float vertices[] = {
            -1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
             1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f
             };

    float texcoords[] = {
            0.0f, 0.0f,
            0.0f, 1.0f,
            1.0f, 0.0f,
            1.0f, 1.0f,
            };

    FloatBuffer texCoordBuffer;
    FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;

    TextureTestRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // set gl options
        gl.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);

        gl.glBlendFunc(GL10.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL10.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_BLEND);

        // create texture
        int textures[] = new int[1];
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        textureID = textures[0];

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

        InputStream is = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.text);
        Bitmap textBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);

        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, textBitmap, 0);
        textBitmap.recycle();

        // create vertex and texcoord buffers
        ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 3 * 4);
        vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

        ByteBuffer tbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * 2 * 4);
        tbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        texCoordBuffer = tbb.asFloatBuffer();

        for (int v = 0; v < 4; v++)
            for(int c = 0; c < 3; c++)
                vertexBuffer.put(vertices[v * 3 + c]);

        for (int v = 0; v < 4; v++)
            for(int c = 0; c < 2; c++)
                texCoordBuffer.put(texcoords[v * 2 + c]);

        vertexBuffer.position(0);
        texCoordBuffer.position(0);

        // set up view matrices
        gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
        gl.glLoadIdentity();

        GLU.gluLookAt(gl, 0.0f, 0.0f, 5.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);

        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textureID);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, texCoordBuffer);

        gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES10.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but no change.Blending is enabled.I also enabled four channels but still no change.I can't find solution.

Comment: Accepted because i think that we tried all of the ways.I suppose i will try draw to canvas and use this texture.Lastly which one is useful?Draw to canvas or using a bitmap?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late...but this seems like a filtering issue.
Try using "nearest" filtering (instead of "linear") for the texture. This can be done with:

```
gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST );
gl.glTexParameterf( GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST );
```

Call this before rendering, and you can then set back to "linear" filtering after rendering by calling both methods again, but using `GL10.GL_LINEAR` instead of `GL10.GL_NEAREST`.

You do not need both calls though, the first one is for when the texture is rendered **smaller** than it's actual resolution, and the second is for when it is rendered **larger**.
In my experience, it is best for the readability of text to use "nearest" filtering when rendering smaller, and "linear" when rendering larger; but that is subjective so you should experiment and find what works best for you.