# Library for drawing text in Opengles for android

Tags: android, opengl-es

is there any library for drawing text with opengles for android?
i dont want to use texture, is there any library that draws text just like shapes in opengles for android?

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android

Comment: the answer says that there are  off-the-shelf/open-source libraries for this job, but i cant find them

Comment: Whilst not a full library, I wrote a tutorial that includes code which can be used freely (public domain license) in any project. You can find it here: http://fractiousg.blogspot.com/2012/04/rendering-text-in-opengl-on-android.html