# Showing dialogues in a game

Tags: android, opengl-es

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Draw text in OpenGL ES (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android)

I'm developing a videogame in Android. For it, I'm using OpenGL-ES.

I have a question about showing text using OpenGL-ES. Is there any method to show test? Because if not, the only way it comes to my mind is having a image with all the alphabet and show text letter by letter, which could be really tough.

Any clue?

Comment: I think some games do just this don't they, with a texture with all of the letters on it and map positions on that texture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to show text in OpenGLES, other than with texture mapped quads as you suggested.

I don't know the particulars of your application, but since you're using android don't forget that you can draw Android Views overtop of an OpenGL view, so depending on what kind of text you need it may make more sense to implement your UI with Android.

Comment: Oh wow. I thought there had to be an easier way... I'm developing a RPG game. So I wanted to use textbox like FF9 (like comics)

Comment: Unfortunately nope. For popup text boxes I think an Android Dialog popup would work well, but you can decide if that fits your game framework or not.