# Android TextView on top of GLSURFACEVIEW for Graphing application

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-activity, textview

THis is a follow up question to my other one shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13654964/how-to-render-text-to-bitmap-and-draw-it)

basically me and my undergraduate project group are creating a 2D graphing application in opengl es 2.0  where the user can enter an equation of a line and have it plot onto the screen. As shown here
[image: sin(x) plot]

So basically I want to add a numerice scale[-10,-9,-8,-7,-6,-5,-4,-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] onto the x and y axis and also label the x and y axis with an "X" and "Y". Basically I have now determined that a textView on top of my GLSURFACEVIEW may be the simplest way to achieve this. Anyone have a link to a tutorial or could help me start coding this view and setting text in there appropriate positions like this:[image: I need a textView that will display the numbers like this]

**How would I code a textView to display the numeric scale and X and Y labels?**

Answer (score 0):

I would create a View on top of GLSurfaceView instead of adding textview, which would cover whole GLSurfaceView.

You can use onDraw(Canvas canvas) to draw the scale using drawText method.