# android opengles 2.0 draw string 2d

Tags: java, android, opengl-es-2.0

The `Activity` load the layout, which has a `GLSurfaceView`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_mixed);

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle.containsKey(EXTRA_KEY_EMAIL)) {
        email = bundle.getString(EXTRA_KEY_EMAIL);
        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextView.setText(myTextView.getText() + " " + email);
    }
    myGLRenderer.setEmail(email);

    myGLSurfaceView = (GLSurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.myGLSurfaceView);

    // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context.
    myGLSurfaceView.setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

    // Set the Renderer for drawing on the GLSurfaceView        
    myGLSurfaceView.setRenderer(myGLRenderer);      

    // Render the view only when there is a change in the drawing data
    myGLSurfaceView.setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_WHEN_DIRTY);         
}
```

[From here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336679/529543) I took the example and fixed ( added the texture declaration and initialisation line )

```
public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {

    private static final String TAG = "MyGLRenderer";

    private String email;
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceCreated: " + config);
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);//gray this is done
    }

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        Log.e(TAG, "onSurfaceChanged: width" + width + ",  height:" + height);
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        doPaintEmail1(gl);
    }

    private void doPaintEmail1(GL10 gl) {

        // TODO do draw all stuff here: paint the email
        Log.v(TAG, "doPaintEmail1: "+email);

        // Create an empty, mutable bitmap
        Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        // get a canvas to paint over the bitmap
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        bitmap.eraseColor(0);

        // get a background image from resources
        // note the image format must match the bitmap format
        //Drawable background = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background);
        //background.setBounds(0, 0, 256, 256);
        //background.draw(canvas); // draw the background to our bitmap

        // Draw the text
        Paint textPaint = new Paint();
        textPaint.setTextSize(12);
        textPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        textPaint.setARGB(0xff, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00);
        // draw the text centered
        canvas.drawText(email, 16,112, textPaint);

        int[] textures = new int[1];
        //Generate one texture pointer...
        gl.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);
        //...and bind it to our array
        gl.glBindTexture(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);

        //Create Nearest Filtered Texture
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL10.GL_NEAREST);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL10.GL_LINEAR);

        //Different possible texture parameters, e.g. GL10.GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL10.GL_REPEAT);
        gl.glTexParameterf(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL10.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL10.GL_REPEAT);

        //Use the Android GLUtils to specify a two-dimensional texture image from our bitmap
        GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);

        //Clean up
        bitmap.recycle();

    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
```

I am expecting to see my example email, but can't see it.

Note I don't use `vertexShaderCode`, `fragmentShaderCode`, nor `GLES20.glCreateProgram()` . Maybe that is missinng, but can't understand why, where it needed.

How to fix this?

At Logcat I see the `doPaintEmail1: foo@example` message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the vertex and fragment shader programs is required for any OpenGL ES 2.0 app to function.  They are not optional.  You should take a look at the 2.0 examples in the Android SDK. If you don't want to use shaders, then use OpenGL ES 1.1, instead.

The third article [here](http://montgomery1.com/opengl/) will guide you to the best examples in the SDK.

Comment: +1, thanks it has something "Render to Texture with OpenGL ES on PowerVR" my phone has that GPU(PowerVR SGX 544) and I have an another app, which doesn't work on this, but on samsung it works.