# Android Open GLES 2.0 rendering text

Tags: android, text, opengl-es, textures

Hi I am new to open GL in android. I tried few things like rendering objects in opengl. But I am not able to find out how to render text in open gles 2.0. Is that really so much tough? I take looks few solutions like rending as texture but is that really a good way? Is there any easy way to render text in open gles 2.0 in android.

Need help. Thank you.

Comment: So yea… rendering text to textures is a pretty good way of doing it, and it's easier than rendering glyphs directly.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL-ES does not provide text rendering APIs.
This question is a duplicate I think, check an answer here:

[Draw text in OpenGL ES (Android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es-android)

I render text using system functions then copy the result to a texture (on iOS, sorry). Variants of this approach are very common. Cross platform methods are somewhat more complex.