# How to draw text clearly in OpenGL ES (Android)

Tags: android, opengl-es, drawtext

First I have read this article about how to draw text in OpenGL ES(Android):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4336679/2757195

I use the same way to draw text in OpenGL ES(Android), except that I use Android JNI API.

My Problem is the text which been drawed in my demo is very fuzzy. And if I increase the size of the same font(such as times 2.0f), it will become more clearer than before. It doesn't make sense!

An example:

font size:12, the rectangle of one character in this font is: RectA(using measureText to get advance).

If the width and height of dest drawing rectangle region is same with RectA, then the character is very fuzzy.

But if I increase the size of font to 60, and the dest drawing rectangle is still RectA, then the character is very clearly.

Why?

Comment: By "increase the size of the font", you mean changing the argument to `setTextSize()`? If so, then this is expected. Drawing the font small and scaling it up will result in blurry text; drawing it large and scaling it down will look clear. For best results, draw it at the same pixel-size you plan to render it.

Comment: @fadden Yes, I use setTextSize to increase the size of same font. I also want to just draw it as the size I want to render, but it doesn't work!