# How to show text on GLES20 android?

Tags: android

recently my app is camera preview on GLSurfaceView.

I use `GLES20` 
 want show text on GLSurfaceView.

before I have a idea. 
create TextView,

`tv.setText("ddd");`

`tv.bringToFront();`
but this not on GLSurfaceView.

How to draw Text on GLSurfaceView `GLES20`?

Comment: Have you seen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es