# How to draw Text on OpenGL android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I want draw Text on OpenGL.

I try use Bitmap,Canvas,Paint.

```
public void GLText(GL10 gl) {
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    bitmap.eraseColor(0);

    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setTextSize(18);
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setARGB(0xff, 255, 0, 255);
    paint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.LEFT);
    paint.setTextScaleX(0.5f);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    canvas.drawText("testGLText", 10.f, 15.f, paint);

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, bitmap, 0);
}
```

and `onDrawFrame` has call `GLText`

and I build my source

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vp81X.jpg)

this source draw Text work.

but background color green.

I want only draw text. 
how to draw text on OpenGL?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OH0ij.jpg)

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es

Comment: @Radhey thanks, but answer is not help.   :(

Comment: Is there any way you could post an actual screenshot instead of a picture of the screen?

Comment: @SporreKing I updated my question picture

Comment: Both imgur links point to the same picture.

Comment: yes, same picture. this picture my problem