# How to render text with line in arcore android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, arcore

I am using ArCore for developing an application for measurement. I have used below link as reference and so far I am able to draw line.
https://github.com/hl3hl3/ARCoreMeasure

I am struggling with "draw text on the detected plane using opengles". ( I believe I have to use opengles  for drawing text)

I have referred below link for the same with no luck so far.

[Draw text in OpenGL ES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1339136/draw-text-in-opengl-es)

Note:- I don't want to use Sceneform library for the same as it has some issues due to which I shifted towards using core Arcore for the development.

Any help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: Yeah, answer 2 is the least complicated, that is: Render common strings to textures, and simply draw those textures.

Comment: Thanks for your answer , I have tried the same but not able to draw anything on the plane

Comment: Well, if you put it too close to the surface where the anchor is, it will get buried, so you have to lift it up some optimal level to work for a variety of surfaces, but not too close to eye-level because it will also not be visable. That's why I try to avoid putting text into the horizontal plane, in addition to having perspective problems with it...

Comment: Did you resolve?